# how to fix graphical lags Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers

since i have i have installed Ubuntu 19 on my laptop, i had some graphical lags: when i try to open all applications it is lagging, but my laptop can still handle my games in 60 fps, (on a 1680x1050 resolution).
I have tried to search for drivers, but nothing was found. 
I already asked this question before, but the people who reacted did not gave helpful answers, so i was just wondering if someone knows how to fix this.

My laptop GPU is: Intel UHD600 (geminilake2x6).

(Sorry for the bad English, i am Dutch).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to graphics drivers for the desktop or games, I have the best luck with the [Padoka PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa?field.series_filter=eoan). I am running an AMD graphics card on a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but it appears to support both intel and AMD and the two versions available support all the latest versions of Ubuntu. With your version of Ubuntu, 19.10, you will need to use the bleeding edge version of Padoka. On the other hand, the [Oibaf repository](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers/) is also popular, and supports all recent Ubuntu versions and nvidia GPUs as well.

I have almost always noticed an increase in graphics performance when utilising either of these mesa opengl and vulkan libraries. It is usually one of the first things I install after upgrading to a new version of the operating system.

In addition, if you experience 3D graphics problems you should make certain you are using Xorg, you can always [try switching from Wayland to Xorg at the login screen](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/).

I hope this response was helpful.